# No response from .NET OpenAI API Betalgo.OpenAI

Tags: c#, .net, openai-api

When I try to create any request to OpenAI I get no response. This line never returns anything:
`var completionResult = await openAiService.Completions.CreateCompletion(r);`
Could you help me pls?
Here is my code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunForest();
        }

        public static async void RunForest()
        {            
            var openAiService = new OpenAIService(new OpenAiOptions()
            {
                ApiKey = "sk-V72p9HoO5BmQaaa34IH1T3BlbkFJDroVJp5fX2g1NirGOf"
            });

            CompletionCreateRequest r = new CompletionCreateRequest()
            {
                Prompt = "Once upon a time",
                Model = OpenAI.GPT3.ObjectModels.Models.TextDavinciV3
            };

            try
            {
                var completionResult = await openAiService.Completions.CreateCompletion(r);
                if (completionResult.Successful)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(completionResult.Choices.FirstOrDefault());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (completionResult.Error == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Unknown Error");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"{completionResult.Error.Code}: {completionResult.Error.Message}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }            
        }
```

I checked my API key, successfully subscribed with credit card and also tried different computers and different APIs, always with the same result

Comment: I hope that's not your real API key

Comment: No it is not :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with the code listed above, but after some surfing, I found a solution posted by JONDJONES.com that shows the same Nuget Package used a little differently.

https://www.jondjones.com/programming/aspnet-core/tools-and-extensions/which-chatgpt-nuget-package-is-the-c-king/

```
using OpenAI.GPT3.Managers;
using OpenAI.GPT3;
using OpenAI.GPT3.ObjectModels;
using OpenAI.GPT3.ObjectModels.RequestModels;
using OpenAI.GPT3.Interfaces;

//Betalgo.OpenAI

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IOpenAIService api = new OpenAIService(new OpenAiOptions()
        {
            ApiKey = "sk-APIKeyGoesHere"
        });

        var completion = await api.ChatCompletion.CreateCompletion(
            new ChatCompletionCreateRequest
            {
                Messages = new List<ChatMessage>
                {
                    ChatMessage.FromSystem("System message"),
                    ChatMessage.FromUser("I'm new to open AI. What material should I read to start using the API that is in C# and beginner level? I'm considering using it to help drive better pricing within the supply chain team as they acquire materials from our vendors. ")
                },
                Model = Models.ChatGpt3_5Turbo0301
            });

        if (completion.Successful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(completion.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.Message.Content);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(completion.Error?.Message);
        }

    }
}
```